# How to implement template method pattern with Spring annotation configuration?

Tags: java, spring

How to implement template method pattern with Spring annotation configuration?

I want to implement one base @Configuration with abstract bean, which should be replaced in each derived config.

All configs will be used together.

```
@Configuration
public abstract class ParentConfig {
    public ComplexBean complexBean() {
        return new ComplexBeanImpl(templateBean(), bean2(), bean3(),...);
    }

    public abstract TemplateBean templateBean();
}

@Configuration
public class Child_1Config extends ParentConfig {
    @Bean
    public ComplexBean complexBean_1() {
        return super().complexBean();
    }

    @Override
    public TemplateBean templateBean() {
        return new TemplateBeanImpl_1();
    }
}
```

I'm confusing that my parent config doesn't contain any beans, only poor java methods. Is it Spring-way? Can it be implemented more elegantly?

Answer (score -1):

[As of Spring 4.3](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12180), you can register a bean of a type `Collection<T>` to autowire (though you can't mix multiple collections or a collection with "loose" beans). In this case, you could collect all of the templates and *then* create the complex beans in one place:

```
@Bean
public List<ComplexBean> complexBeans(Collection<TemplateBean> templates) {
    return templates.toStream().map(ComplexBean::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

(Obviously, that'll be a bit wordier if you can't just use `ComplexBean::new`, but the same principle applies.)

Comment: But what if i have 2 template beans? I want to understand how to solve this problem in general. I want override some beans in derived config and not copy-paste all complex logic from parent.

Comment: @Aleksandr This *is* what you do with two template beans, or any number. You take a collection of templates and create a complex bean for each of them.

Comment: Sorry for not precise comment. I meant 2 template bean types (2 classes). I have big graph of injected dependencies, and i want to generate top level objects with switched implementations of level 2, 3,... classes.

Comment: @Aleksandr As long as they implement a common supertype, which they have to in order to be fed to `ComplexBean`, you can inject as shown here.

Comment: No, they don't implement a common supertype.
For example, I have common car bean with a lot of parts which contains a lot of parts each and so on.
Then I want to create common car but with different wheels or engine.

Comment: @Aleksandr Then you can't have an `abstract TemplateBean templateBean()`, and your question is meaningless.